# Java strange warning "suspicious toArray() call"

Tags: java, warnings

When implementing a `Stream`-class using a delegate stream, I get strange warning by IntelliJ:

> Array of type `java.lang.Object[]` expected, `A[]` found

The code which triggers the warning:

```java
public class MyStream<T> implements Stream<T> {
    private final Stream<T> delegate;

    public MyStream(Stream<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    *snip*

    @Override
    public <A> A[] toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator) {
        return delegate.toArray(generator);
    }

    *snip*
}
```

The full warning:

> Array of type `java.lang.Object[]` expected, `A[]` found
>
> **Inspection info**: Reports two types of suspicious calls to `Collection.toArray()`. The first type is any calls where the type of the specified array argument is not of the same type as the array type to which the result is casted. Example:
>
> ```
> void m(List list) {
>   Number[] ns = (Number[])
>       list.toArray(new String[0]);
> }
> ```
>
> The second type is any calls where the type of the specified array argument does not match the type parameter of the collection declaration. Example:
>
> ```
> void m(List<Number> list) {
>   Number[] ns =
>       list.toArray(new String[0]);
> }
> ```

I somewhat *assume* this is a false positive, caused by type erasure, mostly because I cannot find any sane reason why this would cause a problem, and also because the examples from the warning do not match very well with my code.

However, when thinking about it, I wondered: If this is a false positive triggered because of type erasure, why does it know about `A` at all? Also, Java does usually cast a `A[]` to a `Object[]` implicitly, so why doesn't it here?

So: What is happening here?

Comment: The answer is in the class ReferencePipeline (default implementation of Stream provided by Java). I report the part of your interest: _Since A has no relation to T (not possible to declare that A is an upper bound of T) there will be no static type checking_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ thinks that this is suspicious because your stream is a stream of `T`s, but you are producing an array of `A`s. Note that `A` is the type parameter of the `toArray` method, which is independent of the type parameter `T` for the class. Not much to do with type erasure.

This is indeed a false positive. You are implementing the method for `Stream`, which requires an `A[]` to be returned after all. The method in `Stream` is indeed designed rather unsafely like this, allowing you to pass in *anything* for `A`, no matter what type of stream it is. It is documented that it will throw an `ArrayStoreException` if `A` is the wrong type.

> **Throws**
>
> `ArrayStoreException` - if the runtime type of the array returned from the array generator is not a supertype of the runtime type of every element in this stream

By delegating to `delegate`, you will be throwing an `ArrayStoreException`, *which you should*, (according to the docs) if someone passed a wrong `A` to `toArray` too, assuming the instance stored in `delegate` is correctly implemented. There's nothing wrong here

You can suppress the inspection for this one line by writing this comment above it:

```
//noinspection SuspiciousToArrayCall
```

Comment: Oh my. Don't know how I missed this. I wouldn't call it a false positive though, as it can indeed be a problem, it's just a "documented problem". Seems an odd design choice indeed, but I guess there were some problems with the type bounds of the array constructor (if you want to be able to do `Stream.of(1, 2, 3)).toArray(i -> new Number[3])` etc.)

Comment: @Qw3ry Yeah, I think that's what it's intended for. There's no `A super T` constraint (only the `? super` wildcard, which is not the same thing) in Java, so they had to do it this way.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some different code that can serve to illustrate the problem your IDE is detecting:

```
Stream<Integer> intStream = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
String[] stringArray = intStream.toArray(i -> new String[3]);
```

Or, using your own class (I didn't test this):

```
new MyStream<>(Stream.of(1, 2, 3)).toArray(i -> new String[3]);
```

That code throws a `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` on the second line (the second one would be expected to, as well). But it compiles.

That is exactly the problem with `delegate.toArray(generator);`. You're effectively calling

```
Stream<T>.toArray(IntFunction<A[]>)
```

Where `A` is not guaranteed to be the same as or compatible with `T`. To relate this to the example code above, `T` has the place of `Integer` and `A` has the place of `String`. See the problem?

The JavaDocs of `Stream.toArray` warns about this:

> **Throws**: `ArrayStoreException` - if the runtime type of any element of this stream is not assignable to the runtime component type of the generated array

---

That is the problem that IntelliJ is detecting. You cannot assume that `<A>` and the type-wide parameter `<T>` are going to coincide.

In other words, it's not a false positive and you can use the example above to reproduce it.